# What's an accurate explanation of what is really happening when you use the Java scanner class to receive user input?

Tags: java, class, oop, object, instantiation

I simply need to know if I understand the semantics of this simple Java statement. And I am not the only one. I have Googled this question and lots of people have been asking but everyone gives the same answer or gives regurgitated information from the official documentation. We know how to use it. We want to know how it works. Why.

I know (and so do the others who've asked this) how to use the scanner class. I know how to accept user input and store that input in a variable. But I feel that I should not go any further till I know for sure I understand WHY it works and HOW it works. As it involves Instantiation, Classes, Objects, etc. which is a huge part of this language. It IS the language.

What I would like to do is tell you what I personally think is going on in the code and have you all tell me if that is accurate or not. Ok, here we go.

```
Scanner keyboard;
keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput = keyboard.next();
```

*What is happening here?*

We want to receive user input from the keyboard so we decide to use the scanner class to achieve this.

1.) **The first thing we do is declare our variable. We name it *keyboard* in the declaration.** (Is the variable *keyboard* "type scanner"? What is the variable type here? Scanner, Object, class, etc. It's certainly not a primitive.)

2.) **Now use the java keyword and operator **new** to instantiate (create) an object based off the Scanner. We now assign this object to the *keyboard* variable we previously declared.**

3.) **We pass in System.in as the data source which in this case is the keyboard.**

4.) **Now we want to receive the user's input from the keyboard so we declare a new variable named *userInput*. and then invoke the next() method on the newly instantiated keyboard object and assign this as the value to the new variable userInput** (is this a call to a constructor? Which part is the call to the constructor?)

I've asked a few different questions here and even if this gets downvoted to all hell, please in the very least help me with some answers. I will be VERY grateful. You have no idea. Thank you all.

Comment: Just regarding the first question, it is answered [here.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)  What part do you find unclear?

Comment: `keyboard.next()` is not a constructor call.  It's a method call.  It looks for input, using the input file that was specified when the `Scanner` object named "keyboard" was constructed; a reference to this input file, or information about the input file, is stored in the `Scanner` object.  `next` uses that input file, looks for input, and returns it.

Comment: yeah, I was reading that page slash using it write my question. Basically. when I declare keyboard what is the variable type? Is keyboard now an object once it's instantiated with new scanner(system.in). And which part of this is the constructor method specifically? Thanks

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the comments. Hopefully they are clear enough.

```
// declare a variable of type `Scanner`
Scanner keyboard; 

// call constructor of class `Scanner` and pass `Systen.in` as a parameter to create a new instance 
// and assign its reference to `keyboard`
keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);  

// declare a variable of type `String` and 
// assign to it the return value of `next()` method called on `keyboard` object
String userInput = keyboard.next();
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer. Ok so when "Scanner keyboard;" is first declared it's of type Scanner. First part answered. Ty. You also answered a few other questions I had. The part I am fuzzy on is this. "to create a new instance" By that you mean create a new instance of the Scanner class? which has created an object? Is an object an instance of a class? Does that now make keyboard variable an object? Thanks for answers so far.

Comment: Yes, instance of a class is an object.

Comment: `keyboard` is a reference to an object of class / type `Scanner`.

Comment: Awesome! Ty for answering my questions! very helpful. = )  Accepted!